# Moving average as ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, approximation, signal-processing

Is it possible to represent or approximate the moving average $m(t) = \frac{1}{w}\int_{t-w}^t x(\tau) d\tau$ of a function $x(t)$ as a set of ordinary differential equations $\dot{y} = \ldots$?

I am wondering this because I would like to understand if it is possible to encode the moving average (or a suitable approximation) in state space form.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: It's quite interesting since any measure have errors. People usually hope errors are smaller than the measurement instruments appreciation.

Comment: If you are interested in this area, it should be nice to look at Langevin Equation, Fokker-Planck theory, Brownian Motion, etc...

Comment: Thanks for your input. I don't see immediately how that is applied. Could you provide some pointers how this theory helps to derive an ODE approximation of a DDE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you apply the fundamental theorem of calculus, you will find that
$$ \frac{dm}{dt} = \frac1w x(t) - \frac1w x(t-w). $$
This is a [delay differential equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation), not an ODE.

Perhaps you might find it easier to deal with an exponentially-weighted moving average. If
$$ m(t) = \frac1w \int_{-\infty}^{t} x(\tau)e^{-(t-\tau)/w}\,d\tau. $$
Then 
$$ \frac{dm}{dt} = \frac1w x(t)-\frac1w m(t), $$
which might work depending on what you want if you make $m(t)$ also a state variable.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and the pointer to exponentially-weighted moving average which has a nice ODE form. I assume the moving average DDE cannot be reduced to an ODE. Could you point to some methods of approximating a DDE by an ODE? I found e.g. the following [paper](http://mechatronika.polsl.pl/owd/pdf2010/015.pdf).

Comment: @od3 You can transform a DDE into an ODE approximately by keeping finitely many history points and interpolating between them. It is definitely easier to pick a moving average that gives an ODE.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.