# Moving average of stochastic process

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $X_t$ be a one-dimensional process satisfying the Itô SDE
$$
dX_t = f(X_t)dt + \sigma dW_t,
$$
where $\sigma \in \mathbb R$ and with initial condition $X_0 \in \mathbb R$ given. Now let $\Delta > 0$ and
$$
Y_t := \begin{cases} \frac1t \int_0^t X_s \, ds, &0<t<\Delta,\\ \frac1\Delta \int_{t-\Delta}^t X_s \, ds, &t\geq \Delta,\end{cases}
$$
i.e. the moving average of $X_t$. Clearly, $Y_0 = X_0$.

I found that one can express (for $t \geq \Delta$) the process as
$$
Y_t = X_{t-\Delta} + \frac1\Delta \int_{t-\Delta}^t (t-s)f(X_s) \, ds + \frac1\Delta \int_{t-\Delta}^t (t-s)\sigma \, dW_s.
$$
Is there a *nice* way to write the differential $dY_s$? I suspect that this process satisfies a stochastic delay differential equation (SDDE), but I do not know how to proceed.

For example, for $0 < t \leq \Delta$, we have
$$
tY_t = \int_0^t X_s \, ds,
$$
which implies, as $d(tY_t) = t\,dY_t + Y_t \,dt$,
$$
d(tY_t) = X_t \, dt \implies dY_t = \frac{X_t - Y_t}{t}\,dt.
$$

Comment: There is no nicer way to write the differential than the one you have found. The process does not satisfy an SDDE, neither a stochastic equation (in the usual sense) of any kind - it is just too smooth.

Comment: In case $t \leq \Delta$, it is possible to express $dY_t$ as a function of $X_t$ and $Y_t$. It is not an SDE in the usual sense, but still it is an expression for $dY_t$. Is it possible to do the same for $t > \Delta$?

Comment: For $t>\Delta$, $dY_t =\frac1\Delta(X_t - X_{t-\Delta}) dt$.

Comment: If you couple this with the equation for $X_t$, isn't this a SDE coupled with a SDDE? See for example for ODEs the post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/822323/moving-average-as-ode

Comment: This is rather an ODE, but yes, you can consider these equations as a system of SDDEs (with quite degenerate noise though).

Comment: Yes, I agree. Well, the noise on the $X_t$ component is rather non-degenerate, which makes the $Y_t$ component ``noisy'', too :) But we agree. Thanks!!